# Remove rows from Dataframe with duplicate custom indexes and keep the row having max value for a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have thousands of  pandas dataframe `df`, each with 120 million rows that looks like this:

```
     a   b     c    d    e
111  10  100   200  300  james
112  11  110   210  310  june
112  11  140   210  312  dune
234  12  120   220  333  dane
```

The repeating index is custom index is 112. I want to keep the row with maximum value for column 'b' along with the custom index '112'. So the output would look like

```
      a   b     c    d    e
111  10  100   200  300  james
112  11  140   210  312  dune
234  12  120   220  333  dane
```

What would be a memory and speed efficient way to do this?

Comment: So your index is also one of the columns in the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it corresponds to another column

Comment: Both of the answers are applicable. For the answer by @DataCruncher, just do `df.set_index('1st Column', inplace=True` and you can follow the answer. For the answer by  @L'Artiste, you don't have to do `reset_index`, just do `df.groupby('1st Column').max()`. So, you can mark the one you prefer as correct :)

Comment: Yes, in the example above, I've already moved it to index. I tried, but both seems to be slow. They work fine with smaller data

Comment: Perhaps you would need `dask` package to handle very large size of data. The code will be very similar. See here https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following.

```py
dupe_idx_rows = df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(by='b', ascending=False)

dupe_idx_rows_one = dupe_idx_rows[~dupe_idx_rows.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

out= pd.concat([df[~df.index.duplicated(keep=False)],dupe_idx_rows_one])
```

Alternatively, you can also try using Groupby

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question. The index is actually a column I am interested in, so I have to keep it as it is

Comment: for some reason this seems to be slow

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by the maximum value of a column in each group by using [**`pandas.DataFrame.max`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) :

```
out = df.reset_index().groupby('index').max('b')
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Sorry. I've edited the question. The index is actually a column I am interested in, so I have to keep it as it is

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it out !

Comment: what does passing `b` within the max function do?

Comment: @stackie group by over an entire dataframe will be slow depending on the size of df. See my answer below

Comment: Groupby ends up removing the column "e" in the output